# Default initialization of an object of const type 'NSString *const __strong'?

Tags: c++, ios, objective-c, nsstring

When my Xcode Project compiles with .mm file am getting multiple errors and all the errors are same `"Default initialization of an object of const type 'NSString *const __strong'"` and it's suggesting to put `=nil`. Some .cpp files also included and .mm not making the problem when I put C++ code in .mm the errors are appearing.
We all know that if we put .mm it will compile both Objective-C and C++. The errors are mostly with `NSString *const object;` kind of initialization. I don't want put extern before that or to do some other modification on it because those classes written by someone else in client onshore team, so I should not touch those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A declaration such as

```
NSString *const object;
```

says that `object` is a constant pointer to a `NSString` object. Note the words *constant pointer*, i.e. a pointer that is constant, and can't be modified.

Such a pointer *must* be initialized at time of definition, otherwise it will be forever uninitialized (or initialized to zero if defined in the global scope). You can't assign to it later to initialize it.

If you have such variables declared in other translation units/modules, then you *must* use the `extern` keyword to explicitly tell the compiler that this is a declaration of a variable that exists (and is initialized) somewhere else.

Comment: NSString *const object; is working good the error appearing only when i compile c++ code in .mm @joachim pileborg

Comment: @Codecracker I think "working good" is an exaggeration as it will never be given a valid value.

Comment: yes of course, i'll ask onshore team to do further modifications , thanks for the response @molbdnilo